# How to add writable permission to google cloud app version?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, file-permissions, matomo

Do I have to try to set up a matomo project in the Google App Engine?

I am done with a successful app deploy in the Google cloud App engine and create a perfect App version.
I am app deploy using the below command.

```
gcloud app deploy
```

After I run the app but it shows permission error in the matomo.

How can I change the file permissions of a workspace directory to allow write to it?

I have an attached error screenshot below.

[Matomo error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I8Xd.png)

Comment: Are you using App Engine standard or Flex? try 'Chmod 777 /workspace/temp/' to give the right to this folder?

Comment: I am using a standard App Engine. I didn't find the '/workspace/temp/' in the cloud shell. Can you please give me steps or anything on how to find this directory?

Comment: I fire the 'chmod' command but it is given below error.
chmod: cannot access '/workspace/temp/': No such file or directory

Comment: I review the [MATOMO REQUIREMENTS](https://matomo.org/docs/requirements/). For the database, it requires a SUPER role for the users which means Cloud SQL will not meet the requirement, for the database I recommend you to create GCE instance and install the MySQL DB. Also for the CPU and RAM, you can continue to use App Engine but mount a Google Cloud Storage Bucket as the disk or Use GCE instance and install the Ngnix but still mount the GCS bucket. This could be the recommend GCP infrastructure for MATOMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can't! It's serverless and you code run in a sandbox. Only the `/tmp` directory is writable and it's a in-memory directory. That means 2 things:

- If you store too many things, your instance crashes
- When your instance goes down (scale to 0, maintenance,...) all the data are lost.

To quick fix your issue, use the /tmp directory. And evaluate the impact to not persist these data, and the space that takes in memory.

Comment: No, it's not working.
I modify the cache tracker directory to `\tmp` directory, but it returns the same error as you don't have permission to writable this directory.

Comment: Why do you use a backslash? a slash must be use `/tmp`. [More detail here on the writable directory on app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-temp-files)

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, this `/tmp` uses the app version temporary folder but I need my matomo project temporary folder writable.

Comment: The /tmp is readable and writable. But the data aren't persistant and aren't shared between all the App Engine instances (if many). It's not possible, in serverless products (Cloud Run and Cloud Function also), to have another writable folder. Change your matomo conf to write in it (if possible, I don't know this product)

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, I change matomo conf to write directory but still same issue return like not writable.[error screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ypQzvB9d1nO1Q3AaOzo1XemtdBDvYr6c/view)

Comment: It's normal, the root directory must be /tmp. Here, it's /workspace, and other directory that /tmp aren't writable